# How to extend two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

How to extend two classes in a single class
    e.g.

```
Class1- Common Class for all the other classes
Class2-(Where I use Class2 Extends Class1)
Class3-(Where I use Class3 Extends Class1)
Class4-(Where I use Class4 Extends Class1)

Suppose I introduce a ClassA whose methods are common for Class 2,3,4     
then how do I extend two classes
Class2-Class2 Extends Class1 Extends ClassA
Class3-Class3 Extends Class1 Extends ClassA
Class3-Class4 Extends Class1 Extends ClassA
Note that Class1 and ClassA have no methods in common.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Object based approach:

```js
function foo() {}
function bar() {}
function bam() {}

var one = { foo: foo }; // Common Class for all the other classes
document.write(one.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(one.bar, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'
document.write(one.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

var two = Object.create(one, {
  bar: { value: bar },
}); 
document.write(two.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(two.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(two.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

var three = Object.create(two, {
  bam: { value: bam },
});
document.write(three.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(three.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(three.bam, '<br/>'); // 'function bam() {}'
```

Constructor function based approach:

```js
function foo() {}
function bar() {}
function bam() {}

function One() {}
One.prototype.foo = foo;

var one = new One();
document.write(one.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(one.bar, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'
document.write(one.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

function Two() {}
Two.prototype = new One();
Two.prototype.bar = bar // !

var two = new Two();
document.write(two.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(two.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(two.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

function Three() {}
Three.prototype = new Two();
Three.prototype.bam = bar // !

var three = new Three();
document.write(three.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(three.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(three.bam, '<br/>'); // 'function bam() {}'
```

Class based approach (note: JavaScript "classes" are just syntactic sugar):

```js
function foo() {}
function bar() {}
function bam() {}

class One {
    foo() {}
}
var one = new One();
document.write(one.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(one.bar, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'
document.write(one.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

class Two extends One {
    bar() {}
}
var two = new Two();
document.write(two.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(two.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(two.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

class Three extends Two {
    bam() {}
}
var three = new Three();
document.write(three.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(three.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(three.bam, '<br/>'); // 'function bam() {}'
```

Mix-in based approach (note this places the methods directly on the resulting object):

```js
var one = { foo: foo }; // Common Class for all the other classes
document.write(one.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(one.bar, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'
document.write(one.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

var two = Object.assign({ bar: bar }, one);
document.write(two.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(two.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(two.bam, '<br/>'); // 'undefined'

var three = Object.assign({ bam: bam }, one, two);
document.write(three.foo, '<br/>'); // 'function foo() {}'
document.write(three.bar, '<br/>'); // 'function bar() {}'
document.write(three.bam, '<br/>'); // 'function bam() {}'

function foo() {}
function bar() {}
function bam() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in In Javascript, I have four classes

```
Declaration_Ex_1 (Common class for all classes)  
Browser_Ex_2 Extends Declaration_Ex_1   
Login_Ex_3 Extends Declaration_Ex_1   
Summary_Ex_4 Extends Declaration_Ex_1
```

Suppose I have one more class

```
ElementsCountInPage_Ex_5
```

and I want to call the 1st and 5th both common classes in all the remaining three classes(example Browser_Ex_2 ,Login_Ex_3 and Summary_Ex_4 ) then how can I use the methods of that in other clases.

As we cannot write extends two times for two classes , this will be incorrect isnt it

```
Browser_Ex_2 Extends Declaration_Ex_1
Extends ElementsCountInPage_Ex_5
```